# Infinite extent of spectrum, but also in time in Oppenheim's Discrete Time Signal Processing?

Tags: fourier-transform, time-frequency, bandwidth

In Oppenheim's Discrete Time Signal Processing there's on p. 323 no limited band in both time *and* frequency - wouldn't that violate the Heisenberg Principle?

[image: Systems with Linear Phase on p.322]

Comment: what is the $grd$ operator ?

Comment: @AlexTP: "group delay"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at all. The [Uncertainty Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Signal_processing) says that a function cannot be both limited in time and limited in frequency. More specifically, the product of the signal's widths in time and in frequency (i.e., its time extension $\Delta_t$ and its bandwidth $\Delta_f$) is bounded from below:

$$\Delta_t\cdot\Delta_f\ge C\tag{1}$$

where the constant $C$ depends on the definition of bandwidth and time extension.

Note that $(1)$ is a *lower* bound, not an upper bound, so both widths can be infinite without contradicting $(1)$.

If a function is sharply localized in time then, by the Uncertainty Principle, it cannot be sharply localized in frequency, and vice versa. However, if - as in your example - a function is NOT localized in one of the two domains then this does not mean that it must be localized in the other domain. In may very well be non-localized in both domains, as is the case in the given example for non-integer $\alpha$.

Also take a look at [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/15607/4298) and its answers for more details on the the Uncertainty Principle.

Comment: @Starhowl: The author clearly understands the principle. And my answer is very much related to your question. Your question comes from a misunderstanding of the uncertainty principle. In my answer I tried to point out that a signal with infinite time extension and infinite bandwidth clearly does NOT violate the uncertainty principle.

Comment: @Starhowl, your question wrongly implies that, if a signal's frequency spectrum has infinite support, than its time domain support must be finite according to uncertainty principle. As Matt L described, the principle does not say that. For signal processing applications it's interpreted in the way that a signal cannot be both time and frequency limited... So just like a Gaussian signal $x(t)=e^{-a|t|}$, it can have infinite support in both time and frequency domains.