# Gabor uncertainty and time-frequency resolution

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier, time-frequency, time-series, gabor

I have a question about Gabor's uncertainty theorem, and how it relates to time and frequency resolutions.

As I understand it, Gabor's uncertainty theorem states that the standard deviations of a signal $\sigma_t$ and its Fourier transform $\sigma_f$ satisfy

$$\sigma_t \sigma_f \geq \frac{1}{4\pi},$$

the consequence of this is that you can't decrease the standard deviation of your signal to $0$, without the standard deviation of the Fourier transform increasing to $\infty$. I think I get that.

I have often seen it stated that a *consequence* of Gabor's uncertainty theorem is that we can't resolve both time and frequency, which I think means that we can't make the temporal and frequency resolution both go to $0$. I can see that, because if we were to discretely sample $N$ points from the signal, say at rate $\Delta t$ (this is the temporal resolution), then the Fourier frequencies will be $j/(N\Delta t), j=0,...,N-1$ (with frequency resolution $1/(N\Delta t)$. I can see that decreasing the temporal resolution ($\Delta t$) will increase the frequency resolution, and vice versa, but I'm not sure how this relates to Gabor's uncertainty theorem.

**My question is,** how is Gabor's uncertainty theorem, which is a result about the standard deviations of a continuous signal and its Fourier transform, related to the time and frequency resolution trade-off, which is
a result seemingly about how we sample from the signal. I just can't see it!!!

Edit: an example of someone making that claim [can be found on the wikipedia page of the uncertainty principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Signal_processing) They say "when applied to filters, the result implies that one cannot achieve high temporal resolution and frequency resolution at the same time".

Comment: See [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/15612/235) for more understanding of what's going on.

Comment: [3b1b](https://youtu.be/MBnnXbOM5S4)